# What is purpose of diffusion matrix? What is its role in graph clustering? How do it serve its purpose by equation?

Tags: python, pytorch, graphs, geospatial, graph-neural-network

As titled, I am not quite sure what is purpose of Diffusion Matrix, which is support to clustering graph.

From this article (https://arxiv.org/pdf/2006.05582v1.pdf) I am might able to compute the equation, but what it leads to and how it leads to that result, I am not quite sure.

So I have three questions:

1. What is purpose of diffusion matrix?
2. What is its role in graph clustering?
3. How does it serve its purpose by equation?